# Jquery .load ajax reported deprecated incorrectly

Tags: jquery, jqmigrate

The jquery .load event was deprecated as of version 1.8
(See: https://api.jquery.com/load-event/)

The jquery .load ajax modal has not been deprecated
(See: https://api.jquery.com/load/)

When I try and use the latter command like so:

```
$('#divcontent').load('page.url #divcontainer', function (response, status, xhr) {
    alert('loaded content');
});
```

the JQMIGRATE incorrectly reports that jQuery.fn.load() is deprecated.

I don't believe that the .load ajax function is deprecated. What gives?

Comment: Shouldn't that issue be addressed to JQMIGRATE and not to SO?

Comment: This may be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you using jqmigrate, at all? That's only for migrations from v. <= 1.8.x to v. >= 1.9. You shouldn't need it if your code is current.

Comment: Its good to always have it on the development environment especially when upgrading legacy code from previous versions.

Comment: This is a confirmed bug in JQ Migrate and will be fixed in next version. see: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/issues/138

Comment: You should post your comment as an answer.